# Strange behaviour in CASE expression using dateadd

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm expiriencing some strange behaviour in a SQL statement which is using a `CASE`. It is reproducable with the following example:

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN 1=1
        THEN 'foo'
    WHEN 1=2
        THEN (DATEADD(s, 1435586700, '01/01/1970 00:00:00'))
    WHEN 1=3
        THEN (DATEADD(s, 1435586700, '01/01/1970 00:00:00'))
    ELSE
        'bar'
    END AS result
```

If you execute this on an SQL Server 2008 it returns no result. As soon as you change it for the second or third case to succeed, it returns a value. If you remove those cases completely, it works just fine.

At first I thought it was a problem with `DATEADD` being executed in any case and failing because of passed parameter values. But in my example they are constant and should work in any case.

What is going on here?

Comment: Case expression, not statement...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`case` is an expression whose type is determined at compile-time.  However, the values are not actually evaluated until run-time.

By the rules of type-conversion, I think that the expression will return a `datetime`.  That results in an error for the `'foo'` and `'bar'` values -- when the `when` conditions are met.

Answer (score 1):

You have different types in the various options. This is simply wrong - the case *expression* must have a single type.

In practice, this probably tries to convert the result to `datetime`. And it can't convert `'foo'` to `datetime`.

As for your note about the `dateadd` failing, that wouldn't be a problem - in fact, `case` is one of the few ways to *avoid* evaluating all options.

Case expressions are a bit brittle this way; but this should have already ran your alarm bells - *why* would you ever even consider returning two different data types in the same column? This is bound to cause you trouble sooner or later (in this case, sooner; but it could cause you more trouble in the future yet). Either split the two different possibilities in two columns (e.g. error code + datetime or something), or keep the formatting on the application rather than stuffing it in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try This...
Case expression should be single type so, I changed case option in single type.

```
SELECT
    CASE
    WHEN 1=1
        THEN 'foo'
    WHEN 1=2
        THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),((dateadd(s, 1435586700, '01/01/1970 00:00:00'))))
     WHEN 1=3
        THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),(dateadd(s, 1435586700, '01/01/1970 00:00:00'))
    ELSE
        'bar'
    END AS result
```